# delaying a timer stop in c# visual studios form application

Tags: c#, winforms

in visual studios c# windows form application, I have a timer which want it to stop after a  movement but not straight away can you put in a 5 second delay  in timer.stop(); if possible if not something similar.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      pictureBox1.Top -= 1;
      timer1.Stop();           
}
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(5000);`?

Comment: @Tim: Bad idea, this lags the whole application. Simply add another timer and start the other one after 5 seconds.

Comment: @Robert - True.  Not necessarily a bad thing though if you want the whole application delayed.  Your idea is more robust though.

Comment: @Tim: it is a *bad* thing because it blocks the GUI thread - not what you want even if the "whole application shall be delayed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a counter to specify when to stop the timer: Initialize the counter with, say, 100, if your timer delay is 50ms and you want a "delay" of 5s. Then use

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      pictureBox1.Top -= 1;
      counter--;
      if (counter==0)
         timer1.Stop();           
}
```

Comment: for some reason don't have counter

Comment: You have to create that in your Windows.Forms form: `int counter = 0`.

Comment: got counter working but its not stopping now did everything above in code

Comment: Then you did something wrong. Debug `timer1_Tick` and watch, what happens to `counter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another timer-class: [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Initialize that one on 5 seconds, handle the Elapsed event, in wich you stop your first timer.
Be sure to make it thread safe!
[Thread-Safe Calls to a Windows Forms Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this, i dont think using a timer is the best option here but to satisfy your needs.

```
    Thread runner;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        textBox1.Text = "Amazing"; // initial process
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (runner != null && runner.IsAlive)
            return;

        runner = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            // run your process here
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            StopRunner();
        }));
        runner.Start();
    }

    private void StopRunner()
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        // post process here
    }
```

What it does is it processes your actual request then it'll exit the timer after. I checked if the thread is alive so it wont reprocess it.